# Phonegap push notification not triggering in sleep/standby mode

Tags: android, cordova

I am using this plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

When my phone is in standby (android), it will not receive a google cloud message when wifi is turned on.
Is wifi going into some idle state when my phone is in standby?, and if so, why it doesn't fallback on mobile internet?
If i am only using mobile connection it works like a charm.
But then i found this:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/what-does-keep-wifi-on-during-sleep-mean

My phone settings:
Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep: Always
What is happening here?

Comment: This only happens in your app?, or another apps don't give notifications too?

Comment: @Del i honestly don't know when using this methods.., but when you take whatsapp for example, it is possible although they are most likely using different techniques.

Comment: Today i have had the possibility to se another wifi network and it worked..So i think it isn't code related. Should i answer my own question?

Comment: If you figure why it doesnt work in your wifi, post it in an answer and mark it. It can help anothers to solve similar issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer on this question is personal
My ip wasn't on the whitelist on the server and was blocked for that reason.